# Word order for "What is... that ... called?"

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis

I am having difficulty with finding the natural word order in the following passive construction:

> What are people called who do a lot of unnecessary work?
>
> What are called people who do a lot of unnecessary work?
>
> What are people who do a lot of unnecessary work called?

If I change passive to active, the sentence becomes natural:

> What do you call people who do a lot of unnecessary work?
>
> What does one call people who do a lot of unnecessary work?

But what is the preferred/natural word order, if any, in such sentences, provided I want to stick with the passive?

I was unable to invent a more generic and to-the-point title. Please fell free to edit if you do.

Comment: It's *what*, not *how* in your examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second sentence is not standard English. The other two are both fine, but the last one will become ever more problematic as you add words to the relative clause:

- What are people who do a lot of unnecessary work and then end up having to start all over again called?

In such a case the first variation is much to be preferred.

Comment: Wouldn't adding commas, which separate the relative clause, solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't work because the relative clause in this case is a defining clause. As such it should not be comma-delimited. Here is another sentence containing a defining clause (no commas): *A person who cannot stop working is called a workaholic*. Here is a sentence containing a non-defining clause (commas needed): *My father, who is a workaholic, is called John.*

Comment: The second example *is* standard English, but for a different meaning: "What are X who do Y", with X = "called people" (those who have been called), and Y = "a lot of unnecessary work".

Comment: @jwpat7. Indeed, it hadn't occurred to me that *called* could be interpreted as an attributive adjective.